# Changes made to *.wpp.targets file reflect only after reopening Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have `MyProject.Publish.wpp.targets` file in the root of that project folder.
When I edit this file & publish the project, it doesn't take the new changes.
I have to reopen the Visual Studio and publish for the new changes to apply.

How to fix this.

Using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the files / folders from Windows Explorer into the Solution Explorer. It will add them all. Note this doesn't work if Visual Studio is in Administrator Mode, because Windows Explorer is a User Mode process.